# Why am I getting Notice: Undefined offset: 1 and how can I correct it?

Tags: php

Why am I getting a Undefined Offset here? I was able to successfully do a loop in another page doing something similar.

I am getting the error on the line where it says

```
$subTotal = $subTotal + $totalPrice[$i];
```

inside the while loop.

```
      $totalPrice = [];
      $i = 0;

      while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runquery))
        {
            $id = $value;
            $title = $result['gme_title'];
            $price = $result['gme_price'];
            $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$id];

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$title</td>";
                echo "<td>$id</td>";        
                echo "<td>$quantity</td>";
                echo "<td>$price</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $totalPrice[$i] = $quantity * $price;
            $i++;
            }
            $subTotal = 0;
            while($i > 0)
            {
                $subTotal = $subTotal + $totalPrice[$i];
                $i--;
            }
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan=\"3\" class=\"align\">Total:</td>";
                echo "<td>$subTotal</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Your issue is caused by doing `$i++;` at the end of the `while()` loop. On your last loop, your `$i` value will be 1 larger that your `$totalPrice` last key. You need to do a `$i--;` before using it it your next loop, and you will need to do `while($i>=0)` as you are currently skipping over `$totalPrice[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have only one item returned in your query which leaves you with only one entry in your $totalPrice array(with an index of 0) in the array. When it tries to look up $totalPrice[1] it's telling you it doesn't exist.

You could skip the 2nd while loop and just use the array_sum function.

```
$subtotal = array_sum($totalPrice);
```

You could also skip doing all the $i stuff in general, it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the first loop, `i` points past the last array element.

Just do the `i--` before trying to access elements in the second loop.

As the code stands, you actually don't need to browse through the array a second time, since `array_sum` would do the job for you.